# Sudo Chmod inside shell script

Tags: shell, ubuntu

Why does `sudo chmod <file>` inside my shell script not work? The permissions stay as they were.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo chmod 757 Folder
```

Comment: See for instance https://askubuntu.com/questions/425754/how-do-i-run-a-sudo-command-inside-a-script
The sudo won't work since it needs your sudo password. Putting sudo in scripts is bad practice - you should instead run the script with sudo privilege.

Comment: What's the PHP part of the question?

Answer (score -1):

Remove the sudo from the file. Just write

```
chmod 757 folder
```

And give your script file `+x` permission. It will work.

Comment: Setting a script as executable doesn't give the commands it runs any special permissions.

Comment: @duskwuff I tested this in my ubuntu and it is working

Comment: Probably because your scenario is different from the OP's.

Comment: @duskwuff I only wrote the command that is given in the question which is `chmod 757 folder` it is working as expected. It is changing the permissions

Answer (score -3):

1. In `sudo visudo` add this line to disable the request password when you write the sudo command:

   ```
   www-data ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
   ```
2. Launch the script with the exec function and put sudo inside this with user root only. Now there's no need to enter a password.

   ```
   exec("sudo -u root -S ./create_folders.sh)
   ```

Comment: Yikes! Do not let `www-data` run all commands without entering a password. You've just turned an low privilege account into root.

Comment: @JohnKugelman And to underscore just how bad this is: if there's _any_ remote code execution vulnerability in _any_ PHP script on your system, the attacker now has full root access.

Comment: Thanks @John Kugelman , But I dont find another solution to escape the password request , also for security purpos I prefer this method instead to write the password root in the sudo ..... command .

Comment: I'm not sure the exact syntax, but you can modify that line so instead of `ALL` programs being allowed it only gives access to `create_folders.sh`.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Adequately securing a shell script is… difficult. The one in the OP's question can be exploited to gain root access on most systems.